# Validator font colour not changing

Tags: css, asp.net, regex

I've tried css styles and now the property within the regular expression validator to change the error message font colour, but no dice.

Neither the individual validation or the summary validation is displaying with a red font.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" Text='<%#bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="name" ValidationGroup="v">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegName1" runat="server"
    CssClass="valError"
    ForeColor="Red"
    Display="Dynamic"
    ErrorMessage="You must enter between three and twenty characters."
    ControlToValidate="name"
    ValidationGroup="v"
    ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{3,20}$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Also attempted through the summary and css:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary2" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="false" ShowSummary="true" ValidationGroup="v" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="valError"/>

        .valError {
        color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code works for me, my guess would be you have another style sheet that's overriding the colour that you're setting in the property and other CSS class specified.